# Update a state variable only on loading the page for the first time in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a react component and I want to update the state variable to be false when the page loads for the first time. I am using useEffect for that, but later down the page I am using a third party library that calls a function which has a function to update the same state variable to be true and that is what I want but that runs the useEffect again which makes it back to false.

So, I want to make sure the state variable to be only false when we load/refresh the page

```
useEffect(() => {
    Dosomething();
    DoAnotherThing();
    changeState();
  }[Dosomething,DoAnotherThing,changeState]);

return (
    <>
<ThirdPartyComponent>
//on Load dispatches another function
AnotherFunction();
</ThirdPartyComponent>
</>
)
```

Actions

```
AnotherFunction(){
 changeState(); //I want the state change to happen here but it calls the useEffect back again which makes it false
}
```

So, I am trying to make sure that state variable is false only on load/refresh of the page. I am using Redux for state management

Answer (score 3):

Your useEffect is triggered every time your component is re renderer, if you want it to run only when the component is mounted, you should use useEffect with an empty array as a second argument.

```
useEffect(() => {//stuff},[])
```

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Comment: I just edited my question because useEffect already has dependency array with other functions as useEffect has multiple functions. I do not want it to be re-triggered based on one state variable/function.

Comment: I guess you don't want to have the array empty because of the warnings if you use a linter. Does it work the way you want with an empty array either way ? 
The array is only there to tell your useEffect when to trigger.

Comment: It works with empty array but you are right abut linter. is there any other way?

Comment: You could define your functions in the useEffect, so that the linter does not ask you for more dependency.
Or you could try to understand why Dosomething,DoAnotherThing or changeState change during execution. And maybe split the useEffect in two if needed.
Or you could use a local state initialized with false, as it seems that your State is linked to your component life cycle.  (and maybe create a useEffect with the local state as a dependency to dispatch something when the value goes to True)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a blank array as second argument of useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    changeState();
  }, []);
```

Comment: I just edited my question because useEffect already has dependency array with other functions as useEffect has multiple functions. I do not want it to be re-triggered based on one state variable/function.